# PHP OOP: using $this inside an included subfunction

Tags: php, oop

I having a case to use $this context inside an included function within a class function.
This is bit more complicated to explain in words, So I am giving src codes here.

**Class File:  agents_class.php**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."../../common/apstract_service.php");
class class_proforma extends service
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function getForm($params=false, $do=1){
        if($params){
            include("path/to/custom_func.php");
            return call_user_func_array("custom_func", func_get_args());
        }else{
            return include("another_func.php");
        }
    }
}
```

**custom_func.php file:**

```
<?php
    function custom_func($params, $do){ //here i want to use $this; only $this 
         $this->doJop(); //calling class_proforma's/parent class method from here...
         return include("another_func.php"); //here is another file which is using $this;

    }
?>
```

I want to use $this in custom_func and another_func.
I know passing $this as a argument to cusomt_func can solve this stuff. But the problem is "another_func.php" were it was not possible to change it's $this syntax.

Is there is any way to do???

Comment: first things first, why don't you use an `include_once` before declaring your class ? including a file in each function call might not be a good idea

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. I could be wrong though :)

Comment: of course you CANNOT do that , and you should not even be thinking of doing that. doesnt mean you cant use closures with $this in a function , just mean dont try to do ugly stuffs like that.

Comment: @Yazmat Yeah, It's not a good idea, But I have case like this, There is no other way, also these functions are not for regular use.

Comment: please, stop this "include oriented programming"

Comment: @tereško Hi, Is including **2 files on each request** will make any big trouble??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "mpm"  and "Vlad Preda" says, this is impossible,  So I am going to wrap that function with another class, 
From that class I'll redirect all $this calls to actual $this context.

```
<?php
    class custom_cls{
        $service_ctx = null;
        function __construct($that){
            $this->service_ctx = $that;
        }
        function __call($function, $args) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->service_ctx, $function), $args);
        }
        function custom_func($params, $do){ 
             $this->doJop(); 
             return include("another_func.php"); 
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the only way.

Thanks to all who made reply.